# ClassNotFoundException when I run from a Spring Boot Jar, but not through Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a multiple level Maven project with Spring Boot.

```
ParentProject
|_ Project1
   |_pom.xml
|_ LibraryProject
   |_pom.xml
|_ Project2
   |_pom.xml
```

For ParentProject the parent is defined thus:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

For Project1, LibraryProject and Project2:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>ParentProject</groupId>
   <artifactId>ParentProject</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Project1 and Project2 depend on classes from LibraryProject.  When I execute from Eclipse, Project1 and Project2 both find all of their classes and all of the classes in LibraryProject.  When I create a Project1.jar with

```
mvn clean install package
```

And then run it, I get ClassNotFoundExceptions on the classes that are in LibraryProject.  LibraryProject is a dependency of Project1 and is built before Project1.

ParentProject uses spring-boot-parent as its parent.  It builds in the order:

```
1) LibraryProject
2) Project1
3) Project2
```

I've brought in the maven-compiler-plugin, maven-jar-plugin, maven-remote-resources-plugin.

I'm just out of ideas.  It compiles in eclipse and maven can build it.  But running it creates exceptions.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could you please include the dependency part and `<parent>` tag part of all your pom files? Also, please show us the stack trace of the ClassNotFoundExceptions.

Comment: As I said, I am typing this from an unconnected computer.  I cannot type the entire thing.

Comment: In order to diagnose a problem, we need more information. You can add the information later when they are accessible, peace.

Comment: If you have multi module build than you should not use `spring-boot-parent` as parent of your root...there is a documentation how to do that you have to go via dependencyManagement and import scope (BOM)...furthermore `clean install package` is wrong and duplicates parts...only `mvn clean package` is sufficient...furthermore which of the modules is the real spring boot application?

Comment: All projects are Spring Boot projects (apparently) and using 1 spring boot jar in another isn't possible due to the structure of the jar.

Comment: This was finally solved.  When I imported the project into eclipse, I wasn't paying attention and clicked the "Copy into Workspace" box.  That messed up my changes and allowed Eclipse to build, but not maven.  I destroyed the project and redid it without that checked and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause by ClassLoader, SpringBoot run with `java -jar` has it's own ClassLoader.It will load Class from BOOT-INF/classes and BOOT-INF/lib,but Eclipse will add all dependency to classpath. So Eclipse can find the Class. you can checkout you pom.xml.